# Whether the set $A$ , $ A=\{y\in R : y= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n}) \text{ where } x_n \text{ diverges to } +\infty \}$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let  $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be  continuous  function  and  $A\subset \mathbb R$ be  defined  by  $$ A=\{y\in R : y= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n}) \text{ where } x_n \text{ diverges to } +\infty \}$$
Then $A$  is

A. Connected

B. Compact

C. Singleton

D. None  of  the  above

Now by taking $f(x)=\sin(x)$ I see C. do not hold but A. and B. do. But  how to ensure that what must be correct for all continuous functions or  not  and what special role the divergence of that sequence $x_n$ plays there?

Comment: I agree that $sin(x)$ disproves C, but how does it disprove B?

Comment: But you can easily modify $sin(x)$ to contradict $C$ (hint:  look at $xsin(x)$.

Comment: @lulu : I meant   sin  cannot  disprove B. . C.  is  disproved  by  sin.

Comment: I understood what you meant.  For $sin(x)$ we have $A=[-1,1]$ which is compact.  I am proposing a variant, for which $A$ is not compact.

Comment: So $xsin(x)$  to  contradict B. not C.? I  confused  those  . Thanks.

Comment: Oh, right,  I meant B, not C.  The confusion was at my end.

Comment: Is  the set $A$ is closed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been sort of said, $x\sin(x)$ is a counterexample to (B) and to (C).

But (A) is true. (And this is really awful notation, using "A" for a certain set and also for a condition that set may or may not satisfy).

It's enough to show that if $a,c\in A$ and $a<b<c$ then $b\in A$. Say $x_n\to\infty$, $f(x_n)\to a$, $z_n\to\infty$ and $f(z_n)\to c$.

For each positive integer $k$ there exist $n$ and $m$ such that $x_n>k$, $z_m>k$, $f(x_n)<b$ and $f(z_m)>b$. The intermediate value theorem shows that there exists $y_k$ between $x_n$ and $z_m$ such that $f(y_k)=b$. And $y_k\to\infty$, since $x_n>k$ and $z_m>k$.

Comment: IS the set $A$ is closed ?

Answer (score 5):

To see that $A$ must be connected:

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of $A$ with $a < b$ and let $c$ be some real number in between them (so $c \in (a,b)$).  We need to show that $c\in A$.  To do that we'll show that there are arbitrarily large values $z$ such that $f(z)=c$. Choose $\epsilon > 0 $ so that $a<a+\epsilon<c<b-\epsilon<b$.  By definition of $A$ we can find arbitrarily large $x$ and $y$ such that $|f(x)-a|<\epsilon$ and $|f(y)-b|<\epsilon$.

Choose your cut off $M$. (we want to find $z>M$ such that $f(z) = c$).  But choose $x$ and $y$ as above, requiring that both be larger than $M$. Then $f(x)<c<f(y)$ so the intermediate value theorem guarantees the existence of the $z$ we want.

Comment: IS the set $A$ is closed ?

Comment: @jaysrikrishna  Yes, $A$ is closed.  Sketch:  Take $\{a_i\}\in A$ converging to a real number $L$.  Then, for any $\epsilon>0$, choose $b_i$ such that $|f(b_i)-a_i|<\frac {\epsilon}2$ and choose $i$ large enough to that $|a_i-L|<\frac {\epsilon}2$.  It then follows that $|f(b_i)-L|<\epsilon$ and we are done.